# jQuery UI: Setting draggable options for the dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable dialog and I would like to set dragging options, I don't know how to do it.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/aHb3v/4/) is an example. The red box has the option `cursorAt` set with `{ top: 0, left: 0 }`. I would like to do the same with the dragging of the dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the dialog widget's draggable options, you can reference it like this:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog("widget").draggable("option", "cursorAt", { top: 0, left: 0 });
```

You can do the same with resizable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the dragable to the dialog:

```
$("#draggable, #dialog").draggable({
    cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 }
});
```

You can set the dragable properties on any element that you make dragable.